# Snake Game movement issue

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a snake game by watching a tutorial using java.My problem is that the snake collides with itself from the very begining.

Here is my main class "Main.java"

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame obj = new JFrame();
        Gameplay gameplay = new Gameplay();
        obj.setBounds(10, 10, 905, 700);
        obj.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        obj.setResizable(false);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.add(gameplay);
    }
}
```

Here's my gameplay class named "Gameplay.java"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
    private int[] snakexlength = new int[750];
    private int[] snakeylength = new int[750];
    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean right = false;
    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean down = false;

    private ImageIcon rightmouth;
    private ImageIcon upmouth;
    private ImageIcon downmouth;
    private ImageIcon leftmouth;

    private int lengthofsnake = 3;

    private Timer timer;
    private int delay = 100;

    private ImageIcon snakeimage;
    private ImageIcon titleImage;
    private ImageIcon enemyimage;

    private int[] enemyxpos = {
        25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425,
        450, 475, 500, 525, 550, 575, 600, 625, 650, 675, 700, 725, 750, 775, 800, 825, 850 };
    private int[] enemyypos = {
        75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450, 475,
        500, 525, 550, 575, 600, 625 };

    private Random random = new Random();

    private int xpos = random.nextInt(34);
    private int ypos = random.nextInt(23);

    private int score = 0;
    private int moves = 0;

    public Gameplay() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (moves == 0) {
            snakexlength[2] = 50;
            snakexlength[1] = 75;
            snakexlength[0] = 100;

            snakeylength[2] = 100;
            snakeylength[1] = 100;
            snakeylength[0] = 100;
        }

        // draw title image border
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(24, 10, 851, 55);

        // draw the title image
        titleImage = new ImageIcon("snaketitle.jpg");
        titleImage.paintIcon(this, g, 25, 11);

        // draw border for gameplay
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(24, 74, 851, 577);

        // draw background for the gameplay
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(25, 75, 850, 575);

        // draw scores
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("Score: " + score, 780, 30);

        // draw length
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("Length: " + lengthofsnake, 780, 50);

        rightmouth = new ImageIcon("rightmouth.png");
        rightmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakexlength[0], snakeylength[0]);

        for (int a = 0; a < lengthofsnake; a++)

        {
            if (a == 0 && right == true) {
                rightmouth = new ImageIcon("rightmouth.png");
                rightmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakexlength[a], snakeylength[a]);
            }
            if (a == 0 && left == true) {
                leftmouth = new ImageIcon("leftmouth.png");
                leftmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakexlength[a], snakeylength[a]);
            }
            if (a == 0 && up == true) {
                upmouth = new ImageIcon("upmouth.png");
                upmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakexlength[a], snakeylength[a]);
            }
            if (a == 0 && down == true) {
                downmouth = new ImageIcon("downmouth.png");
                downmouth.paintIcon(this, g, snakexlength[a], snakeylength[a]);
            }
            if (a != 0) {
                snakeimage = new ImageIcon("snakeimage.png");
                snakeimage.paintIcon(this, g, snakexlength[a], snakeylength[a]);
            }

        }

        enemyimage = new ImageIcon("enemy.png");

        if ((enemyxpos[xpos] == snakexlength[0] && enemyypos[ypos] == snakeylength[0])) {
            scorelength();
            ratrandom();
            /*
             * score++; lengthofsnake++; xpos = random.nextInt(34); ypos =
             * random.nextInt(23);
             */
        }
        enemyimage.paintIcon(this, g, enemyxpos[xpos], enemyypos[xpos]);

        for (int b = 1; b < lengthofsnake; b++) {
            if (snakexlength[b] == snakexlength[0] && snakeylength[0] == snakeylength[0]) {
                right = false;
                left = false;
                up = false;
                down = false;
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
                g.drawString("Game Overs", 300, 300);
                g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
                g.drawString("Spacebar to AGAIN play", 350, 340);
            }
        }

        g.dispose();
    }

    public void scorelength() {
        score += 5;
        lengthofsnake++;
    }

    public void ratrandom() {
        xpos = random.nextInt(34);
        ypos = random.nextInt(23);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            lengthofsnake = 3;
            score = 0;
            moves = 0;
            repaint();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            moves++;
            right = true;
            if (left == false) {
                right = true;
            } else {
                left = true;
                right = false;
            }
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            moves++;
            left = true;
            if (right == false) {
                left = true;
            } else {
                left = false;
                right = true;
            }
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            moves++;
            up = true;
            if (down == false) {
                up = true;
            } else {
                down = true;
                up = false;
            }
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            moves++;
            down = true;
            if (up == false) {
                down = true;
            } else {
                up = true;
                down = false;
            }
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
        if (right == true) {
            for (int r = lengthofsnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                snakeylength[r + 1] = snakeylength[r];
            }

            for (int r = lengthofsnake; r >= 0; r--) {
                if (r == 0) {
                    snakexlength[r] = snakeylength[r] + 25;
                } else {
                    snakexlength[r] = snakeylength[r - 1];
                }
                if (snakexlength[r] > 850) {
                    snakexlength[r] = 25;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
        if (left == true) {
            for (int r = lengthofsnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                snakeylength[r + 1] = snakeylength[r];
            }

            for (int r = lengthofsnake; r >= 0; r--) {
                if (r == 0) {
                    snakexlength[r] = snakeylength[r] - 25;
                } else {
                    snakexlength[r] = snakeylength[r - 1];
                }
                if (snakexlength[r] < 25) {
                    snakexlength[r] = 850;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
        if (up) {
            for (int r = lengthofsnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                snakexlength[r + 1] = snakexlength[r];
            }

            for (int r = lengthofsnake; r >= 0; r--) {
                if (r == 0) {
                    snakeylength[r] = snakeylength[r] - 25;
                } else {
                    snakeylength[r] = snakeylength[r - 1];
                }
                if (snakeylength[r] < 75) {
                    snakeylength[r] = 625;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
        if (down == true) {
            for (int r = lengthofsnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                snakexlength[r + 1] = snakexlength[r];
            }

            for (int r = lengthofsnake; r >= 0; r--) {
                if (r == 0) {
                    snakeylength[r] = snakexlength[r] + 25;
                } else {
                    snakeylength[r] = snakeylength[r - 1];
                }
                if (snakeylength[r] > 625) {
                    snakeylength[r] = 75;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

Need a help to find out the problem

Comment: Now would probably be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Use `paintComponent(g)`, not `paint(g)`... Also, don't reload the images each time you paint. Load them only once.

Answer (score 2):

It's this part of your code that looks to be causing the problem:

```
if(snakexlength[b] == snakexlength[0]&& snakeylength[0] == snakeylength[0])
```

We can immediately see that the second part will always evaluate to true (this looks like an error in itself),  so it's clearly some problem with the first part:

```
snakexlength[b] == snakexlength[0]
```

It's not immediately clear *why* this happens, but if I had to make an assumption I'd say that that it's something to do with how you 'initialise' the snake given that the error apparently occurs straight away. I noticed that in several places you set `snakexlength[r] = snakexlength[r-1]` or vice-versa, so most likely it's a problem in the control flow of your program around here that means two  indexes in `snakexlength` are briefly equal.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7T9GuR-YFfrX19xMU9neHBDb3M here's the source code with files. You can take a look